# is_page not working when loading javascript with add_action in functions.php

Tags: javascript, conditional-tags

This code is working in my functions.php and it's loaded properly:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_custom', 50);
function js_custom() {
    wp_register_script( 'js_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js_custom' );
}
```

However, this is not working and not loaded:

```
if ( is_page(273) ) {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_custom', 50);
    function js_custom() {
        wp_register_script( 'js_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'js_custom' );
    }
}
```

Why it's not loaded? I am on the page with the id equal to 273.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue once. I found that running the `add_action` call outside the conditional worked. So try this:

```
    function js_custom() {
        if ( is_page(273) ) {
            wp_register_script( 'js_custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', false, null);
            wp_enqueue_script( 'js_custom' );
        }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_custom', 50);
```

Comment: Hmm, I am getting this error: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'js_custom' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Sorry! Edited answer. The conditional had to go inside the function call. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working ;). Btw. I would consider this as a bug in WP. Should I post it to the WP team? Or this is not a bug?

Comment: I'm not qualified to say if it's really a bug or not. This is a simple enough fix to wrap the contents of your function in the conditional, that we can continue to do that.

Comment: @Derfder It's not a bug but I'll admit the add_action, do_action, add_filter, apply_filter stuff isn't very intuitive when you're getting started with WordPress.  Var dump $wp_query in the actual is_page function with the two difference scripts and you'll see the difference.